# C# XML Serialization - How to get XML node structure as string

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I don't know if it is possible to get xml node structure as string in C#. I need to read everything inside opticxml node into a simple plain string after web service call.
I have xml like this:

```
    <opticxml>
        <Optic>
            <header>
              ...
            </header>
            <items>
                <item>...</item>
                <item>...</item>
                ...
            </item>
            <experimental>
                <frame>...</frame>
                <lens>...</lens>
            </experimental>
        </Optic>
    <opticxml>
```

Then I have class for response like this:

```
    [XmlRoot("Data")]
    public class Data4Response
    {
        ...
        [XmlElement("opticxml")]
        public string opticxml { get; set; }
    }
```

I get correct response from WS call, than I convert BASE64 encoded string to string (UTF8) and when I want to parse it to Data4Response class I get exception.

```
    public DataResponse()
    {
        Data = new Data4Response();
        ...
    }

    public static DataResponse DeserializeMessage(string input)
    {
        ...
        ret = (DataResponse)s.Deserialize(reader);
        ...
    }
```

What is the solution for this? How should I configure XmlElement("opticxml") that I get Optic node as string?

Thank you for help.

Comment: I would create a recursive extension method. string xmlString(this XmlElement). Then for each of the child elements, return child.xmlString()

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the performance implications, but you could try this:

```
var XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(input); // assuming "input" contains your Xml as above
var opticNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/opticxml").InnerXml;
// at this point, opticNode will be a string containing everything inside the opticxml element.
```

The LoadXml and SelectSingleNode together executed 1,000,000 times in 8.6 seconds as a (very) rough benchmark.